# Asserting iterators equality in CppUnit

Tags: c++, cppunit

I've been starting to use CppUnit library. And everything worked fine, but now, I get stuck with asserting iterators using `CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL`. So there is my code:

```
void TestingClass::test_adjacent_find()
{
    // Set up
    int a [5] = {1,2,3,3,5};
    int b [5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int c [1] = {1};

    std::list<int> lst;
    lst.push_back(1);
    lst.push_back(1);
    lst.push_back(5);

    // Check
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(a+2, my_adjacent_find(a , a+5, pred_eq<int>));
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(b+5, my_adjacent_find(b, b+5, pred_eq<int>));
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(c+1, my_adjacent_find(c, c+1, pred_eq<int>));
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(lst.begin(), lst.end()); // problem is here
}
```

When I'm running this test I'm getting the error below.

```
/opt/local/include/cppunit/TestAssert.h:49:13: 
Invalid operands to binary expression 
('OStringStream' (aka 'basic_ostringstream<char>') 
and 'const std::_List_iterator<int>')
```

If I comment the line with iterators, then it compiles without any problems. So what am I doing wrong? And how should I assert equality of two iterators? By the way, I use xcode 4.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL` macro documentation in `TestAssert.h`:

`#define CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(expected,actual)`

Requirement for `expected` and `actual` parameters:

- They are exactly of the same type
- **They are serializable into a std::strstream using operator <<**
- They can be compared using operator ==.

The last two requirements (serialization and comparison) can be removed by specializing the `CppUnit::assertion_traits`.

So the root cause of your problem is that `std::list::iterator` could not be serialized to `std::strstream`. You need to write your own `CppUnit::assertion_traits` specialization for it as documentation describes or just avoid `CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL` and use `CPPUNIT_ASSERT`:

```
CPPUNIT_ASSERT(lst.begin() == lst.end());
```